# Compile error if use vuetify.js with sass's lighten function

Tags: sass, vuetify.js

I am integrating the vuetify.js into my existing vue.js project. I have an existing sass variable defined as:

```
$list-group-active-text-color:  lighten($list-group-active-bg, 40%) !default;
```

It compiles fine before the integration. But after integration, I received the following compile error,

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> $list-group-active-text-color:  lighten($list-group-active-bg, 40%) !default;
>
> $color: ("base": #e91e63, "lighten-5": #fce4ec, "lighten-4": #f8bbd0, "lighten-3": #f48fb1, "lighten-2": #f06292, "lighten-1": #ec407a, "darken-1": #d81b60, "darken-2": #c2185b, "darken-3": #ad1457, "darken-4": #880e4f, "accent-1": #ff80ab, "accent-2": #ff4081, "accent-3": #f50057, "accent-4": #c51162) is not a color.

It appears the `lighten` function is misintepretted as one of the vuetify's lighten-`x` color variable. Does anyone see a similar issue too?

Comment: It sounds like you've identified the issue as a conflict between the existing `lighten` function and the one Vuetify uses.  Have you tried to rename the one in your existing project so that they can co-exist?